# Python requests files option looping and adding data issue

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I have a code to find out all images in a folder and added there location to an array.

```py
import os
urls = []
for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()+"/product_images"):
    if file.endswith((".jpg",".jpeg",".png",".JPG",".JPEG",".PNG")):
        x = os.getcwd()+"\\"+file
        urls.append(x)
```

I have filed called files which look like this

```py
files = {
            'photo_0': ('image_0.jpg', open('E:/images/1.jpg', 'rb'), 'image/jpeg'),
            'photo_1': ('image_1.jpg', open('E:/images/2.jpg','rb'), 'image/jpeg')        
        }
```

Now what I want is to use all images location which stored in array will be added to files filed like this

Suppose I have 4 images location into urls[] array
Now it will be like this.

```py
files = {
            'photo_0': ('image_0.jpg', open('E:/images/image.jpg', 'rb'), 'image/jpeg'),
            'photo_1': ('image_1.jpg', open('E:/images/abcd.jpg','rb'), 'image/jpeg'),
            'photo_3': ('image_2.jpg', open('E:/images/sddg.jpg', 'rb'), 'image/jpeg'),
            'photo_4': ('image_3.jpg', open('E:/images/sdfs.jpg','rb'), 'image/jpeg')        

        }
```

And then I will send this files to an api

```py
response = requests.request("POST", url_and,data=data_android,files=files,headers=headers)
print(response.text.encode("utf-8"))
```

Thanks in Advance 
Atik Rahman

Comment: So what’s the problem you are having?

Comment: I can't find a way to generate 

`files = { ... }` from array into code to send the all images in array to requests